# I want to know from which network drive my .bat file is pulling the files

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SQL SERVER job and the job type is "Operating System(CmdExec). It is run as SQL Agent Service Account. The command is `F:\Tools2\SSIS\MonthlyProcess.bat`

Can anyone please explain me what this job is doing? This is supposed to be an SSIS job where the files are pushed from the Mainframe server onto a network drive and this `.bat` file is pulling the flat files from the shared network drive onto the local F drive.

How do I know from which network drive the `.bat` file is pulling the files and how do I edit the .bat file? Because whenever I try to open the `.bat` file a command window opens and closes pretty fast.

Comment: Right click on the file, and then open with ... notepad. If you don't see notepad in the right click menu, open notepad and then drag the file to the notepad window. Once you have done that, you'll have a better idea of what its doing and then you can update the question and make it a bit more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The batch file can be edited with any text processor, like Notepad. Right click on it, you should see a "Modify" item menu. If not, open Notepad and browse to your file in the open file explorer.

Once the file is opened, you can see what it does. From the fact that your batch file is in a folder called SSIS, I suspect it does something like :

```
dtexec /f Drive:/Path/To/Some/SSISFile.dtsx
```

The `/f` flag tells you what SSIS package is being executed.

Comment: This is what the .bat file has "F:
cd\tools2\SSIS\MonthlyProcess\MonthlyProcess
dtexec /f "Package.dtsx" /Rep "EW" >> F:\Tools2\Log\MonthlyProcess.log
Now can you please explain what its doing?

Comment: So that does answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the comment you posted in Dominic Goulet's answer, your bat file is

1. Insuring it is in the F: drive
2. Changing the directory to \tools2\SSIS\MonthlyProcess\MonthlyProcess\
3. Using dtexec to execute the package package.dtsx (probably located in the above directory)
4. Directing the output to f:\tools2\Log\MonthlyProcess.log

You should retrieve the package.dtsx file from that server in the F\tools\SSIS\MonthlyProcess\MonthlyProcess\ directory and edit it with visual studio to see what the package is doing.  You should also check with the original programmer (if he is still available) to ask why we used such a convoluted process to run this SSIS package, and to get any documentation on this process before you attempt to make any changes.